# How do I prevent vim from automatically editing my input?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I copy/paste from one `.cpp` to another in `vim`, and `vim`, confident that it knows what I want to do better than me, edits my entry. For example, if I copy/paste this:

```
// A comment.
Some(code);
```

`vim` would replace it with this:

```
// A comment.
//    Some(code);
```

How do I disable that?

Comment: You might be looking for this:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_automatic_comment_insertion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option may be to remove the "r" formatoption, with:

```
:set formatoptions-=r
```

and also possibly other options, all of which I found at:
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/how-can-i-get-vim-to-stop-putting-comments-in-front-of-new-lines

Comment: (also an indirect pointer to the vim.SX site)

Answer (score 2):

Go into paste mode:

```
:set paste
```

after pasting, you want to end paste mode:

```
:set nopaste
```